# Only select the very first p tag using first-of-type

Tags: html, css

the :first-of-type css selector finds all occurrences that is the first of it's type within a group of siblings. Therefore in this case:

HTML

```
<div id="aaa">
  <p>Blaha</p>
  <header><p>Mooxa</p></header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#aaa p:first-of-type { color:red; }
```

both p tags will be colored red.

Does anybody know how to make only the very first p tag inside div#aaa, the one with "Blaha" in it color red?

Ps. I can't add any classes or ids Ds.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hz5Qe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `>` symbol which refers only direct child elements.

```
#aaa > p:first-of-type { color:red; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hz5Qe/1/)**

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to write this in scss, like this?

#aaa {

  > p:first-of-type { color:red; }

}

Comment: @RascalCapac You could use `&` character like: `#aaa { & > p:first-of-type { color:red; } }`. It's called *[parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)*.